# MongoDB : "message": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findById')"

Tags: mongodb

I am creating api i get this error in postman "message": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findById')"

```
async function getCustomer(req, res, next) {

  let Customer
  
try {
    Customer = await Customer.findById(req.params,id)
    
if (Customer == null) {
      
return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Cannot find Customer' })
    }
  
} catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: err.message })
  }

 
 res.Customer = Customer
 
 next()
}
```

any help please?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
let Customer
```

When calling Customer.findById() the local Customer will be called (the one declared with let).

Name the customer with a small letter i.e

```
let customer
customer = await Customer.findById()...
```